# php-fpm/nginx giving scripts wrong path info

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I use an nginx webserver and I've been trying to stop a problem where sites are given the wrong `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` variable. This breaks some scripts. The problem seems to be that nginx is giving the wrong variables to FPM.

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is "/index.php/index.php" and it should be "/index.php"

This is the nginx server PHP configuration...

```
server {
        listen 192.168.0.3:80;
        server_name cacti;
        access_log /home/admin/cacti_access_log;
        error_log /home/admin/cacti_error_log;
        root /var/www/sites/cacti;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/admin-socket;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        }
}
```

fastcgi_params...

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: What is the complete configuration? Why are you including fastcgi_params and defining them separately in the block too?

Comment: That is everything relevant to the problem. It is a bit of a mess because I've been trying a few different things. The result is the same without the include, because at this point it doesn't add anything. So between it and the include there is a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Have you tried the default configuration with `include fastcgi_params`? What CMS do you use, and what kind of routing system it uses? Have you defined any rewrites for the CMS in nginx? These are all very much relevant points in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I've updated and included the entire server config. It's just for cacti, and there are no rewrites as you can see. I'm not sure what you mean by routing system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, move `include fastcgi_params` before the `fastcgi_param` entries. nginx processes these directives in order, so configuration inside `fastcgi_params` file will override your definition in the `server` block.

Then, use thse settings for `PATH_INFO` and `PATH_TRANSLATED`:

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Okay, I've done all that but `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is still `/index.php/index.php` - and PATH_TRANSLATED was already set the way you just mentioned.

Comment: I think you meant for `PATH_TRANSLATED` to be `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` because now it seems to work!